# How to call an imported async function using node require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, require

I am trying to fetch latitude and longitude data using an async function and Puppeteer.

I expect to see the latitude and longitude values I fetched. However, I get the following error instead.

> const latLong = await getLatLong(config);
>                          ^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

node.js

```
const getLatLong = require('./util/latLong');
const latLong = await getLatLong(config);
```

latLong.js

```
const getLatLong = async ( city, state, ) => {
  ...
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  ...
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto( url, waitUntilLoad, );
  await page.type( placeSelector, placeString, );
  await page.click( runButtonSelector, waitUntilLoad, );
  ...
  const results = await page.evaluate( ( lat, long, ) => {
    const latitude = Promise.resolve(document.querySelector(lat).value);
    const longitude = Promise.resolve(document.querySelector(long).value);
    const out = { latitude, longitude, }
    return out;
  }, [ latitudeSelector, longitudeSelector, ] );
  ...
  await browser.close();
  return results;
}

const latLong = async ({ city, state, }) => {
  const out = await getLatLong( city, state, );
  return out;
};

module.exports.latLong = latLong;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to make the function from where you're calling `getLatLong` async.

Comment: Or just use `.then()` on the returned promise.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thank you for your comment. How would your idea look in code? Feel free to provide an answer. Your idea would very likely help expand my understanding of async and promises.

Comment: @Mowzer - Using `.then()` seems like something you should learn from basic educational material on promises.  If that's really something you don' tknow, please find and read a few tutorials on using promises as it will benefit your programming in other ways too. 
 `getLatLong(config).then(latLong => { console.log(latLong);});`

Comment: @jfriend00: The question was really more about *where* to use `then`, not *how*. As there are a number of different possibilities. Thanks.

Comment: That's a bit longer discussion.  Maybe show some examples of different circumstances and ask a new question.

Comment: @jfriend00: I meant where in this case. Not in general.

Comment: If you only have one promise operation and there's no other compelling reason to use an `async` function wrapper, I use `.then().catch()` as it seems simpler to me.  If you have multiple promise operations that you want sequenced and you don't need individual catch handlers on each one, then `await` usually leads to simpler code.  The rest is a personal style choice.  I suspect that as the language continues to develop, there will be more and more advantages to using `await`.  In all cases, don't forget proper error handling which the accepted answer here does not show.

Comment: Why are you wrapping `Promise.resolve()` around this `const latitude = Promise.resolve(document.querySelector(lat).value);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, `await` can be used in the `async` function only. Wrap it in the `async`, for example like this:

```
const getLatLong = require('./util/latLong');

(async () => {
    const latLong = await getLatLong(config);
    console.log(latLong);
})();
```

But keep in mind that all of the code which depends on the `latLong` result has to be in the `async` wrapper too.